# Error building apk using apktool

Tags: android

I am trying to decompile and then recompile an apk using apktool.
I used apktool like this:
[image]

No changes made to the files. I just decompiled and recompiled them but apktool is showing error. The problem persists when i do make some changes to the xml files.
What should I do now?

Regards

Comment: try `apktool d Phone.apk` only.

Comment: still the same problem..

Answer (score 4):

I am answering this just in case somebody gets stuck with same problem.
If you are not concerned about resources of apk you can skip the extraction of resources by using the following command

```
apktool d -r my_app.apk
```

this command will skip the decompling of res folder.

Answer (score 0):

That problem is caused by apktool improperly decoding some positional XML elements. You can fix this manually by adding `formatted="false" to all those lines that it errors on or wait for Apktool 2.0 (set for a release in about 1.5 months).

We added about 25 unit tests for this exact problem and hopefully this example is fixed on 2.0. You may build 2.0 from source and test this.

Comment: The version I am using is 1.5.2. Is it a problem with this version only? Where can I find the source for apktool 2.0?

Comment: Its a problem with any version except 2.0. The source of Apktool is on Github/Googlecode and is a Google search away :)